# I need an idiomatic solution in Dart on a client socket application

Tags: sockets, dart, async-await, console, future

Testing a server socket and its client in a Dart console.
I find the problem that I have to introduce a delay `await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1));` so that the listening cycle of the sockects can be carried out at the same time that I request a message through the console.

I'm sure there is a smarter solution in Dart, but I haven't found a way to do it.

To run the code, simply copy/paste the code into a `server.dart` and `client.dart` file and run them.

Here the client:

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
import 'dart:io';

InternetAddress HOST = InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4;
const PORT = 7654;
void main() {
  Socket.connect(HOST, PORT).then((socket) async {
    print('connected to server $HOST$PORT');

    socket.handleError((error) {
      print('handleError $error');
    });
    socket.write('Hello, World from a client!');

    socket.cast<List<int>>().transform(utf8.decoder).listen(onData, onDone: () {
      print("Done");
    }, onError: (error) {
      print('onError: $error');
    });

    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1));
      stdout.write("Enter your msg : ");
      var msg = stdin.readLineSync();
      socket.write(msg);
    }
  }).catchError((error) {
    print('catchError: $error');
  });
}

onData(data) {
  print('onData: ' + data);
}
```

It is a simple cycle that requests a keyboard input that is sent to the server, this always works, but if I remove the **await Future.delayed ...**, I do not receive the responses from the server.

I am not very happy with this approach as a solution.
Is there an alternative, maybe an isolate, a well-made future, or a stream?

And here the server:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;

InternetAddress HOST = InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4;
const PORT = 7654;

void main() {
  ServerSocket.bind(HOST, PORT).then((ServerSocket srv) {
    print('serversocket is ready');
    srv.listen(handleClient);
  }).catchError(print);
}

void handleClient(Socket client) {
  var client_id =
      '${client.hashCode} => ${client.remoteAddress.address}:${client.remotePort}';

  print('Connection from: $client_id');
  client.write("Hello from Simple Socket Server!\n");

  // data from client:
  client.cast<List<int>>().transform(utf8.decoder).listen((msg) {
    print('${client.hashCode}: $msg');
    // Here switch msg
    client.write('Reply: ' + msg);
    //client.close();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a synchronous loop: `while (true)  { ... readLineSync() ... }`. The entire loop is synchronous, which means that no other code will run before the loop ends (which, having the condition `true`, is never).
You have to give up control during that synchronous loop to allow other, asynchronous, code to also run.

So, *if* you could change the `readLine` line to `var msg = await stdin.readLine();`, then you wouldn't be blocking anyone while waiting for input. Sadly you can't, there is no asynchronous `readLine`.
So, an alternative would be to use a `LineSplitter` on stdin to get the lines asynchronously:

```
var stdinLines = ;
...

stdout.write("Enter your msg : ");
await for (var msg in stdin.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(const LineSplitter())) {
  socket.write(msg);
  stdout.write("Enter your msg : ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I wrote:   
```Stream readLine() =>
    stdin.transform(utf8.decoder).transform( LineSplitter());```   
And then in the loop:   
```stdout.write("Enter your msg #${i++}: ");
      readLine().listen((msg) {
        socket.write('$msg\nEnter your msg #${i++}: ');
      });```